# Golub and Van Loan: Another Practice Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am slowing picking my way through the classic: Matrix Computations (3rd Edition) by Golub and Van Loan.  I am trying to get back into the math mindset here.  I have more linear algebra background than I would like to admit, but some of these practice problems are still elusive.  I'm trying to make sure I am really understanding this first section. Here is problem **P1.1.1**:

**P1.1.1** Suppose $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n{\times}n}$ and $x \in \mathbf{R}^{r}$ are given. Give a saxpy algorithm for computing the first column of $M=(A-x^{}_{1}I)\cdots(A-x^{}_{r}I)$.

I am assuming that I am supposed to first use some rules of linear algebra to rearrange the right side of the equation to reduce it to a more trivial matrix multiplication operation using the distributive properties of matrix operation.  I tried expanding the right side but didn't see any way to simplify that too much.

I am also assuming that we are supposed to implement the saxpy formulation of the matrix multiplication algorithm from section 1.1.13 which explains the saxpy algorithm for computing the columns of a matrix multiplication.

However I can't quite see the key to this practice problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the version of the book I found, I don't see any mention on "saxpy". But anyway, look first at the expression that actually gives the first column of this matrix. (Better look at it on the right.)

Comment: @metamorphy my problem is that I am not seeing an expression for the first column, considering we are multiplying $r$ matrices.  I can come up with something for the case where $r=2$ but having a hard time for higher $r$.  For instance, when $r=2$: $m^{}_{j} = {\sum_k^n}(a^{}_{kj} - x^{}_{2})(a^{}_k - x^{}_{1}) + c^{}_{j}$

Comment: I mean, the first column of a matrix $A$ is $A\cdot(1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$.

Comment: @metamorphy Seems I'm missing some basic issue for most of these questions.  for example P1.1.4: Specify an algorithm for computing $(XY^T)^k$ where $X,Y{\in}R^{n{\times}2}$.  This again is some matrix multiplication, then multiplied by itself $k$ times.  I'm not quite seeing how to modify these algorithms to arbitrary about of multiplications.

Comment: @metamorphy Right I understand your expression for the first column of $A$, but the question asks for the first column fo $M$, which when $r=2$ involves multiplying the first column of $A$ by each row of $A$, of course also taking into account the scalars $x_r$

Comment: Again - look at it on the right (and don't stress $r = 2$ too much).

Comment: @metamorphy thanks so much for your time here.  I am trying to "look at it on the right", but I am not quite sure what you mean by that?  Start with the right-most part first $(A-x_rI)$?

Comment: A matrix times a column is again a column. (I'm exceeding an affordable limit of comments here, sorry.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81596/discussion-between-jeffery-the-wind-and-metamorphy).

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I recently worked through this problem, and would like to share my insight... so to make this work as a saxpy formulation, we require some column vector $C$ that will be updated with an assignment $$C := b_kA(:,k)+C$$ where we are looping over the $k$ columns of $A$, and $b_k$ is a scalar.

The way I tackled this, was to first try and find some recursive element in the original equation that could be used as $C$. So I tried to set $$C:=A+x_1I$$ initially, and then $$C := C(A+x_2I) = AC+x_2C$$ (it's easy to check that $C$ and $A$ commute). So it seems we are onto something here...if we set $B:=C$ and then $C:=x_2C$ before entering the $k$-loop, the right-hand-side above becomes $$AB+C$$ and we just need to reduce it to calculating the first column, that is $$A(:,k)B(k,1) + C(:,1)$$ (bearing in mind we need to update $B$ and $C$ in the outer loop when looping over $r$).

Putting it all together: first set

$$C := \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and then

```
for i = 1:r
  B := C
  C := x_i*C
  for k = 1:n
      C := A(:,k)B(k,1) + C
```

I tested on one problem with three terms and it seems to work ok...but if anyone picks up a problem, please let me know.